# Defining complex type in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

Trying to define a complex element which can also have an attribute.
XML looks like

```
<dummy id="asdsa">
   <Item> 
   </Item>
   <Item> 
   </Item>
<dummy>
```

I do:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element name="dummy">
      <complexType>
        <attribute name="id"/>
        <sequence>
        <element name="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </element>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Update:  If I put the attribute after the sequence it works.  If anyone can give me the answer why, I'll give them the answered question mark:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <element name="dummy">
      <complexType>
        <sequence>
        <element name="Item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        </element>
        </sequence>
        <attribute name="id"/>
      </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="numero_etiqueta">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:minLength value="13"/>
                <xs:maxLength value="13"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="codigo_objeto_cliente">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="objeto_postal">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="numero_etiqueta"/>
                <xs:element ref="codigo_objeto_cliente"/>                                               
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've found out, `xs:attribute` declarations must come after the declaration of the model group for a complex type declaration. The reason is simply that this is what the XML Schema grammar requires. The relevant excerpt from the [schema for schemas (s4s) meta-schema](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#normative-schemaSchema) is

```
<xs:group name="complexTypeModel">
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element ref="xs:simpleContent"/>
  <xs:element ref="xs:complexContent"/>
  <xs:sequence>       
    <xs:group ref="xs:typeDefParticle" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:group ref="xs:attrDecls"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:choice>
```